# handling a lot of parameters in luigi

Tags: python, parameter-passing, luigi

In a lot of my projects I use [luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a pipelining tool. This made me think of employing it to implement a parameter search. The standard `luigi.file.LocalTarget` has a very naive approach to deal with parameters, which is also shown in the doc's examples:

```
def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget("data/artist_streams_%s.tsv" % self.date_interval)
```

Namely, the parameters get saved in the file name. This makes it easy to check if a certain parameter combination is already computed. This gets messy as soon as the parameters for a task are more complex.

Here is the very simple idea of a parameter search:

```
import luigi
class Sum(luigi.Task):

    long_ = luigi.Parameter()
    list_ = luigi.Parameter()
    of = luigi.Parameter()
    parameters = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("task{}_{}_{}_{}.txt".format(self.long_,
                                                              self.list_,
                                                              self.of,
                                                              self.parameters))

    def run(self):

        sum_ = self.long_ + self.list_ + self.of + self.parameters
        with self.output().open('w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(str(sum_))


class ParameterSearch(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):

        list_of_parameter_combinations = [
            {
                "long_" : 1,
                "list_" : 2,
                "of" : 3,
                "parameters" : 4

            },{
                "long_" : 5,
                "list_" : 6,
                "of" : 7,
                "parameters" : 8
            }
        ]

        for pc in list_of_parameter_combinations:
            yield Sum(**pc)
```

Sure, in this example, all four parameters can be encoded in the file name, but it does not require a lot of phantasy, that this approach can reach boundaries. Think for example of array-like parameters.

My follow up idea was to store the parameters and the result in some kind of **envelope** object, which can then be saved as a target.
The file name could then be some kind of hash of the parameters for a first fuzzy search.

There is the envelope class

```
class Envelope(object):

    @classmethod
    def hashify(cls, params):
        return hash(frozenset(params.items()))

    def __init__(self, result, **params):

        self.params = {}
        for k in params:
            self.params[k] = params.get(k)

    def hash(self):
        return Envelope.hashify(self.params)
```

Then, there is the new Target, that enhances the LocalTarget and is able to check if all parameters inside the envelope are matching:

```
class EnvelopedTarget(luigi.file.LocalTarget):

    fs = luigi.file.LocalFileSystem()

    def __init__(self, params, path=None, format=None, is_tmp=False):
        self.path = path
        self.params = params

        if format is None:
            format = luigi.file.get_default_format()

        if not path:
            if not is_tmp:
                raise Exception('path or is_tmp must be set')
            path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'luigi-tmp-%09d' % random.randint(0, 999999999))
        super(EnvelopedTarget, self).__init__(path)
        self.format = format
        self.is_tmp = is_tmp

    def exists(self):
        path = self.path
        if '*' in path or '?' in path or '[' in path or '{' in path:
            logger.warning("Using wildcards in path %s might lead to processing of an incomplete dataset; "
                           "override exists() to suppress the warning.", path)
        if self.fs.exists(path):
            with self.open() as fin:
                envelope = pickle.load(fin)

                try:
                    assert len(envelope.params) == len(self.params)
                    for param,paramval in self.params.items():
                        assert paramval == envelope.params.get(param)

                except(AssertionError):
                    return False
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem here is, that using this target adds some boilerplate which originally luigi aims to minimize. I set up a new base task

```
class BaseTask(luigi.Task):

    def output(self, envelope):
        path = '{}{}.txt'.format(type(self).__name__, envelope.hash())
        params = envelope.params
        return EnvelopedTarget(params, path=path)

    def complete(self):

        envelope = Envelope(None, **self.param_kwargs)

        outputs = flatten(self.output(envelope))
        if len(outputs) == 0:
            warnings.warn(
                "Task %r without outputs has no custom complete() method" % self,
                stacklevel=2
            )
            return False

        return all(map(lambda output: output.exists(), outputs))

    def run(self):

        result, outparams = self.my_run()

        envelope = Envelope(result, **outparams)

        with self.output(envelope).open('w') as fout:
            pickle.dump(envelope, fout)
```

The resulting `EnvelopedSum` Task would then be pretty small:

```
class EnvelopedSum(BaseTask):

    long_ = luigi.Parameter()
    list_ = luigi.Parameter()
    of = luigi.Parameter()
    parameters = luigi.Parameter()

    def my_run(self):
        return sum(self.param_kwargs.values()), self.param_kwargs
```

This task can be run in the same fashion as the `Sum` task in the beginning.

Note: this example implementation of how to envelope the luigi-task-results is far from stable and is more of a illustration of what I mean by envelope the results and the parameters.

**My question is**: Isn't there a simpler way to deal with a lot of complex parameters in luigi?

**Followup-question**: Has anyone thought about holding record of the code-version (and/or package versions of subtaks) on which the parameter search had been performed?

Any comments on where to read on on this topic are also appreciated.

**Note:**

you probably need some imports to make this running:

```
from luigi.task import flatten
import warnings
import pickle
```

Answer (score 2):

You might get a better response to this sort of proposal on the mailing list. The Luigi task code already does generate an MD5 hash of the parameters to generate a unique task identifier which you could grab.

[luigi/task.py#L128](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/cdd63df/luigi/task.py#L128)

```
# task_id is a concatenation of task family, the first values of the first 3 parameters
# sorted by parameter name and a md5hash of the family/parameters as a cananocalised json.
param_str = json.dumps(params, separators=(',', ':'), sort_keys=True)
param_hash = hashlib.md5(param_str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: And how to deal with hash collisions?

Comment: @bluenote10 should be exceedingly rare. in any case, it is nice to put the parameters that vary the most first in the list so they provide some more obvious human readable differentiation in the task ids when debugging.